# How does Q2 fit into JPOS when connecting to a banks switch?

Tags: jpos

I am relatively new to JPOS and I have only used it to pack and unpack messages and I would like to understand how Q2 can help me.  At the moment I am developing an application that receives requests from mPOS to a central server using REST and then I transform the messages to ISO8583 using JPOS which I then forward to a banks switch.  I am supposed to maintain 1 persistent connection to the bank's switch.  Can Q2 help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad, so it will be this answer.

I believe [jPOS tutorials page is exactly what you need](http://www.jpos.org/tutorials).

In particular the first 3:

1. [Basic gateway](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-gateway.pdf): How to Implement a gateway from scratch
2. [Customize your gateway](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-custom-gateway.pdf): Adding custom code to customize it.
3. [jPOS REST tutorial](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-rest.pdf): How to implement a REST API interface in Q2.

Then you can use concepts of the previous 3 tutorials to build a transaction manager that process REST request to query the bank switch using ISO8583 interface

Comment: Thanks @Andres, I have managed to go through the tutorials and have managed to deploy.  Very helpful.